# For loop not quite working

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, for-loop

This is my first endeavor into for loops and I'm having some problems.  I'm trying to write a program that will ask for how many points two teams scored per quarter and then display total points and the winning team.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
    int scoreA = 0;
    int scoreB = 0;

    cout << "This program calculates the average score of 10 tests." << endl;

    for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter = counter + 1)
    {
        cout << "Enter Team A's quarterly points: ";
        cin >> scoreA;
        cout << "Enter Team B's quarterly points: ";
        cin >> scoreB;
        scoreA = scoreA + scoreA;
        scoreB = scoreB + scoreB;
    }

    cout << "Team A's Score: " << scoreA << endl;
    cout << "Team B's Score: " << scoreB << endl;
    if (scoreA > scoreB)
    {
               cout << "Team A wins";
               }
    else
    {
        cout << "Team B wins";
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should write what the problems are.

Answer (score 1):

The variable in which you stores sum of scores and variable in which you inputs from user should be different. Do like (*read comments*):

```
int sumB=0 , sumB=0; // added this 
for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter = counter + 1){
  cout << "Enter Team A's quarterly points: ";
  cin >> scoreA;
  cout << "Enter Team B's quarterly points: ";
  cin >> scoreB;
  sumA = sumA + scoreA;
  sumB = sumB + scoreB;
  //  ^      ^
}
```

In your code you are doing like for example `scoreA = scoreA + scoreA;` and `cin >> scoreA`  both statements over writes each other effects during the loop, and same happens with `scoreB`.

Hence accordingly change next lines in your code too, like:

```
cout << "Team A's Score: " << sumA << endl;
cout << "Team B's Score: " << sumB << endl;
if (sumA > sumB){
  // your code
}
else{
 // your code
}
```

Additionally, because you are new to c++ and SO, I would like to suggest a link: [*The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Or preferably `sumA += scoreA`.

Comment: @Jite Yes better to use `+=` :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not saying specifically what isn't working with the loop, but I see in your for loop the following:

```
cout << "Enter Team A's quarterly points: ";
cin >> scoreA;
cout << "Enter Team B's quarterly points: ";
cin >> scoreB;
scoreA = scoreA + scoreA;
scoreB = scoreB + scoreB;
```

So you are overwriting the scores in scoreA and scoreB on every iteration (`cin >> scoreA`), and then doubling them (`scoreA = scoreA + scoreA`).